# How to retrieve all post titles of a specific post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I would like to use the titles within a select element in a form I am echoing to the client side. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Are you trying to return all post titles for all posts under specific post type? Is that right?

Comment: Sorry! Yes exactly, I have made a custom post type, created a few posts of this type, and I want to echo a form with a select element which allows a user to select one of the titles (They represent projects) to donate to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Query all post titles of a specific post type**

```
// Function that returns post titles from specific post type as form select element
// returns null if found no results.

function output_projects_list() {
    global $wpdb;

    $custom_post_type = 'page'; // define your custom post type slug here

    // A sql query to return all post titles
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s and post_status = 'publish'", $custom_post_type ), ARRAY_A );

    // Return null if we found no results
    if ( ! $results )
        return;

    // HTML for our select printing post titles as loop
    $output = '<select name="project" id="project">';

    foreach( $results as $index => $post ) {
        $output .= '<option value="' . $post['ID'] . '">' . $post['post_title'] . '</option>';
    }

    $output .= '</select>'; // end of select element

    // get the html
    return $output;
}

// Then in your project just call the function
// Where you want the select form to appear
echo output_projects_list();
```

Comment: This is an overly complex function for something that can easily be done using the API that WordPress provides in the WP_Query class. The answer provided by @ialocin is far better. You shouldnt need $wpdb for this.

Comment: Yes and what is the point of the comment? :)

Comment: @Brian What is `far better` about the other answer? This is technically faster as you are grabbing only the data that you need from mysql. The other answer (easier answer) grabs all the data into memory then modifies it afterwards in PHP. Thats more work for PHP. Both are acceptable but each have their strengths. If you know mysql then this isn't overly complex at all. Its pretty simple.

Comment: I agree with @JoeMoe1984, This function isn't as simple as the other answer... BUT it is MUCH more efficient from a memory perspective. SQL is a FAR better place (than wp_list_pluck(...)) to reduce/extract the valuable information from. Yes, it is slightly more complex, but your system will thank you for that...

Answer (score 17):

You could - and in my mind, should - use API functions to get the data.

```
// query for your post type
$post_type_query  = new WP_Query(  
    array (  
        'post_type'      => 'your-post-type',  
        'posts_per_page' => -1  
    )  
);   
// we need the array of posts
$posts_array      = $post_type_query->posts;   
// create a list with needed information
// the key equals the ID, the value is the post_title
$post_title_array = wp_list_pluck( $posts_array, 'post_title', 'ID' );
```

Comment: +1 for `wp_list_pluck()`. I always forget about that one...

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the pluck! How had I not seen this before??

Comment: +1 for the one-liner.... One-liners always rock!

Comment: Beware this will easily overload sites with lots of posts. Running WP_Query with `'posts_per_page' => -1` without sufficiently restrictive filters is an easy way to crash a site or run out of server resources.

Comment: You're not wrong @sbnc.eu but the question was how to get all the titles.

Comment: Right, and what I am saying that this method is only viable for small sites. If there are lots of posts a custom query is a must. Performance and memory footprint difference can be to large to ignore.

Comment: @sbnc.eu Thank you – feel free to post a solution for it.

Answer (score 5):

For an **hierarchical** post type, we have the built-in:

```
wp_dropdown_pages( 
    [ 
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'echo'      => 1, 
        'name'      => 'wpse_titles', 
        'id'        => 'wpse-titles' 
    ] 
);
```

that will generate a *select* element with *post titles* and the *post ID* as the option value.

**Example:**

```
<select name='wpse_titles' id='wpse-titles'>
    <option class="level-0" value="1">AAA</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="2">BBB</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CCC</option>
</select>
```

It's not clear from the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_pages/) for `wp_dropdown_pages()`, but it's a wrapper for `get_pages()` and also support it's input arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have always done things like this is using `get_posts` and `foreach` like something below:

```
// Create our arguments for getting our post
$args = [
  'post_type'=>'custom-slug'
];

// we get an array of posts objects
$posts = get_posts($args);

// start our string
$str = '<select>';
// then we create an option for each post
foreach($posts as $key=>$post){
  $str .= '<option>'.$post->post_title.'</option>';
}
$str .= '</select>';
echo $str;
```

Comment: This is working well, thank you. I am attempting to add 'selected' to the option currently saved, I've tried a lot of different bits of code and finally have come to this, which is allowing me to update the option but the 'selected' isn't being added to the correct one. Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

`       $str .= '<option '. ($post == $value2 ? 'selected=selected' : '') .'>'. $post->post_title .'</option>';`

Many thanks for any suggestions

p.s. Sorry I don't seem to be adding code correctly, tried backticks